# glScene function to convert object's 3D coordinates to viewport 2D coordinates

Tags: delphi, glscene

Is there any build-in function in glScene (Delphi) for converting 3D (xyz) position coordinates of the object to a screen 2D (xy) coordinates of that object shown on GlSceneViewer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gluProject` from the glu library is usually used to perform this function.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml

I am unfamiliar with glScene, but it appears that `gluProject` is used in `TGLSceneBuffer.WorldToScreen(const aPoint : TAffineVector) : TAffineVector;`.  This should do what you want.